# Unable to import test modules, Python Azure Function

Tags: python, azure-functions, python-unittest

Seems like there has been a lot of movement with the `import` of tests and shared modules. I tried the [documented methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#import-behavior), but none of them work...

What am I missing?

**Scenario**:

- Python Azure Function with the following directory structure:

```
image-tokenizer (project-root)
|_.venv
|_imagetokenizer (function itself)
  |___init__.py
  |_function.json
|_tests
  |___init__.py
  |_test_validate_url_param.py
|_host.json
|_local.settings.json
|_requirements.txt
```

[image]

- I'm trying to run a test using `unittest`
- The function I want to test *inside*, the Azure Function code `main()`: `imagetokenizer/__init__.py`:

```
    def validate_url_param(raw_url):

        if raw_url is None:
            raise ValueError("Missing required parameter 'url'.")

        if not isinstance(raw_url, str):
            raise ValueError("Parameter 'url' must be a string.")
        
        try:
            decoded_url = urllib.parse.unquote(raw_url)
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Parameter 'url' could not be decoded. Error: {e}")

        storage_url_regex = re.compile(
            r'^https://[a-z0-9]{3,}\.blob\.core\.windows\.net/.*$', re.IGNORECASE)
        
        if not storage_url_regex.match(decoded_url):
            raise ValueError("Parameter 'url' must be a valid Azure Storage URL.")
        
        return decoded_url
...
```

- The test code for the above function: `tests/test_validate_url_param.py`:

```
import os
import unittest

from imagetokenizer import validate_url_param # THIS IS THE PROBLEM

class TestValidateUrlParam(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_valid_url(self):
        raw_url = 'https%3A%2F%2Faccount.blob.core.windows.net%2Fcontainer%2Ffolder1%2Ffolder2%2Fblob.jpg'
        self.assertTrue(validate_url_param(raw_url))

    def test_invalid_url(self):
        raw_url = 'not_a_url'
        self.assertFalse(validate_url_param(raw_url))
```

- From a terminal where `pwd` == `image-tokenizer` (project root) with venv activated: `python -m unittest discover`

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.test_validate_url_param (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_validate_url_param
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\me\image-tokenizer\tests\test_validate_url_param.py", line 5, in <module>
    from imagetokenizer import validate_url_param
ImportError: cannot import name 'validate_url_param' from 'imagetokenizer' (C:\Users\me\image-tokenizer\imagetokenizer\__init__.py)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

- If I try `from .. import validate_url_param` or `from ..imagetokenizer import validate_url_param`, I get the error: `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

There is something going on where the function *inside* my Azure Function's `__init__.py` file cannot be imported into my `unittest`.

Ideas?

**EDIT 1**:

@SiddheshDesai, I think your directory structure is different than mine, right?

```
image-tokenizer (project-root)
|_imagetokenizer (?)
  |_.venv (Your .venv is at this level, mine is a level above)
  |_HttpTrigger1 (function 1)
    |___init__.py
    |_function.json
  |_HttpTrigger2 (function 2)
    |___init__.py
    |_function.json
|_tests
  |___init__.py
  |_test_validate_url_param.py
|_host.json
|_local.settings.json
|_requirements.txt
```

**EDIT 2**:

Ugh...my issue was that I had defined all the functions inside the `main()` function. The `import` statement could only import `main`. I moved the function definition outside `main`, now it works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***I used below method to import file from another folder in python function:-***

**My file structure:-**

[image]

When I tried to import the file directly with

```py
from imagetokenizer import validate_url_param
```

I received the same error code as yours, Refer below:-

[image]

In my test_validate_url_param.py I added this code and the import validate_url_param was successful, Refer below:-

**test_validate_url_param.py code:-**

```py
import os
import unittest

import sys


sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from imagetokenizer.HttpTrigger1 import validate_url_param

class TestValidateUrlParam(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_valid_url(self):
        raw_url = 'https%3A%2F%2Faccount.blob.core.windows.net%2Fcontainer%2Ffolder1%2Ffolder2%2Fblob.jpg'
        self.assertTrue(validate_url_param(raw_url))

    def test_invalid_url(self):
        raw_url = 'not_a_url'
        self.assertFalse(validate_url_param(raw_url))
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Make sure you add the lines below and import the module accordingly :-

```py
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from imagetokenizer.HttpTrigger1 import  validate_url_param
```

*I have HttpTrigger1 folder with function under imagetokenizer folder **thus I used from imagetokenizer.HttpTrigger 1***

[image]

> **Reference:-**
>
> [Import Modules From Another Folder in Python -
> GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/import-modules-from-another-folder-in-python/)

Comment: This functionality is not in the official [Azure Function Python Developer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#import-behavior). Opening an issue on their Github...

Comment: added **Edit 1** in original post.